# Unable to play sound (wav) on event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, avfoundation

I need to play a short sound. This is the code I wrote

In my header I have:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AddItemController : UIViewController < ... , AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
...
AVAudioPlayer *audio;
}

...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AVAudioPlayer *audio;

@end
```

In the .m file:

```
- (void)playSound {
    NSURL *url;
    if (error) {
        url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Resources/error.wav"]];
    } else {
        url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Resources/finished.wav"]];
    }
    audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    audio.delegate = self;
    [audio play];
}

-(IBAction)addItem:(id)sender { 
    if ( ... ) {
        error = true;
        [self playSound];
        return;
    }

    ...

    error = false;
    [self playSound];
}
```

No warning nor issue with the code. All the other functions are working. Just I can't hear any sound.

## #

Ok! I found the solution by myself. Sorry if I bothered you.

Hope my solution will be useful for somebody.

```
- (void)playSound
{
    NSURL *url;

    NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"error.aif"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
        [audio prepareToPlay];
    }
    [audio play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` and `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` functions, from the [AudioToolbox](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007916) framework.

Comment: AVSudioPlayer is not intended to present a player in way whatsoever, you are thinking of AVPlayer.

Comment: Ooops, my bad... Corrected the answer, Thanx... : )